Intel RAPL constraint 2 disappeared from zone 0 with kernel 5.15.0-122-generic
Up until kernel 5.15.0-119-generic, I was able to set the "peak_power" constraint for the CPU package.  Here's a snippet of the output from powercap-info intel-rapl -z 0:
  name: package-0
  enabled: 1
  max_energy_range_uj: 262143328850
  energy_uj: 7573908711
  ...
  Constraint 2
    name: peak_power
    power_limit_uw: 121000000
    time_window_us: 0
    max_power_uw: 0

As of kernel 5.15.0-122-generic, Constraint 2 no longer exists in the reported info.
I've checked the kernel release notes, and although they mention RAPL several times, I don't see anything obviously relevant.
My CPU: lscpu(1) shows:
Model name: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
Request
I've been setting peak_power in order to greatly extend my battery life, ensure the fan doesn't run, etc.
Does anyone know how I can restore the ability to set peak_power?  Or can anyone explain why it's stupid to use this method?  :-)

It is not stupid to use  this method. I do similar, but also use TCC offset to also limit via processor temperature. I have set my power limits in BIOS. See if this old answer can be used to help.
